# Deshabilitar opciones de un select

Tags: select

Me pueden ayudar, este es mi código necesito que dependiendo el estado que hay en una tabla se deshabiliten opciones y otras permanezcan

El código lo deje en el primer comentario

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="estadoTicket" class="form-control select2Gral" name="datos[estado]" required>
<option value="">Selecciona Estado</option><?php
$estadosticket=array('solicitado','procesando','re-abierto','rechazado','terminado','responsiva','cancelado');
foreach($estadosticket as $edo){
    if($estado=='solicitado'){
        $mostrar='disabled';
        if(current_user_can('egc_soporte-asignar-tickets')){
            if($edo=='terminado' || $edo=='procesado' || $edo=='rechazado' || $edo=='responsiva'){ $mostar='';}
        }else{
            if($edo=='cancelado'){ $mostar='';}
        }
        if($edo=='cancelado'){ $mostar=' disabled ';}
    }
    ?>
    <option <?php echo $mostrar;?> value="<?php echo $edo;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($edo);?></option><?php
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que si miras tu código verás que si el estado no es `solicitado` nunca se define la variable `$mostrar` así que tienes que definirla fuera del `foreach`.

El resto del código es bastante confuso y no se ve lo que pretendes. Te recomiendo que lo expliques mejor o intentes hacerlo con un `switch`.